# Elasticsearch declare field as null

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to declare a field to null not with **null_value**.

Are **""** and **null** equivalent?
If I do not write anything to field, will ES set set the null automatically?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the field to be `null` just don't index it.

**""** (empty string) is a non-null value (see the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html)), and will be stored in the document (but not in the inverted index).

Comment: How should I set that field? For example:  PUT my_index/my_type/1
{ "name" : "good"
  "status_code": null
}

Comment: Here, it says "empty string " is not stored : http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ioyu/dealing-with-null-and-not-null-values-in-elasticsearch-queries

Comment: It is. See the link to official doc attached. You can easily check it - index a field with empty string value, run match_all query, and check the source.

Comment: The article says that empty string won't be stored in the inverted index, so you will be able to find it only using exists query. That's true. Anyway, the value still will be in the document's source.

Comment: What is the difference to set "null" or unsetting that field?

Comment: No difference for inverted index, and for the way how you will query those fields. The only difference is how it will be stored in the document's source.